# Animation breaks when trying to change the color of the loaded model

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a model with animation from Blender. When I upload it to the site, everything is ok, the animation works. I want to change the body color of the model, but when I try to do this, the body stops perceiving the animation and becomes static. The rest of the elements continue to animate. I can't figure out where the error is, please help!

```
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js'
const gltfLoader = new GLTFLoader()

let mixer = null;

gltfLoader.load(
'models/bot/model.glb',
(gltf) => {
    gltf.scene.traverse((child) => {
        if(child instanceof THREE.Mesh && child.material instanceof THREE.MeshStandardMaterial){
            if(child.name === 'Body'){
                child.material =  new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial( { color: 'red', wireframe: true } );
                child.material.needsUpdate = true
            }
        }
    })

    mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(gltf.scene);
    const action = mixer.clipAction(gltf.animations[1])

    action.play()

    scene.add(gltf.scene)
}
)
```

//Animation

```
const clock = new THREE.Clock()
let previousTime = 0


const tick = () =>
{
const elapsedTime = clock.getElapsedTime()
const deltaTime = elapsedTime - previousTime
previousTime = elapsedTime

mixer && mixer.update(deltaTime)

// Update controls
controls.update()

// Render
renderer.render(scene, camera)

// Call tick again on the next frame
window.requestAnimationFrame(tick)
}

tick()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
child.material.skinning = true;
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.